# Azure pipeline does not stop running Spring Boot application after finishing tests

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure-pipelines, okhttp, micrometer-tracing

I run integration tests with Cucumber against a Spring Boot 3 application.
Maven command is: mvn verify -B -ntp -Pcucumber,pipeline

The tests run fine, but at the end I get a message:

```
The STDIO streams did not close within 10 seconds of the exit event from process '/usr/bin/mvn'. This may indicate a child process inherited the STDIO streams and has not yet exited.
```

After that the stage keeps running until it times out (at 1 hour).

```
##[error]The operation was canceled.
```

In between I do see loglines for OkHttp:

```
2023-12-06 13:41:47.981 [OkHttp TaskRunner] DEBUG [traceId= spanId=] [reqId=] [sessionId=]o.internal.concurrent.TaskRunner - Q10014 starting              : OkHttp ConnectionPool
2023-12-06 13:41:47.981 [OkHttp TaskRunner] DEBUG [traceId= spanId=] [reqId=] [sessionId=]o.internal.concurrent.TaskRunner - Q10014 finished run in 441 µs: OkHttp ConnectionPool
2023-12-06 13:41:56.075 [OkHttp TaskRunner] DEBUG [traceId= spanId=] [reqId=] [sessionId=]o.internal.concurrent.TaskRunner - Q10000 starting              : OkHttp ConnectionPool
2023-12-06 13:41:56.076 [OkHttp TaskRunner] DEBUG [traceId= spanId=] [reqId=] [sessionId=]o.internal.concurrent.TaskRunner - Q10000 finished run in 550 µs: OkHttp ConnectionPool
2023-12-06 13:41:56.076 [OkHttp TaskRunner] DEBUG [traceId= spanId=] [reqId=] [sessionId=]o.internal.concurrent.TaskRunner - Q10004 starting              : OkHttp ConnectionPool
2023-12-06 13:41:56.077 [OkHttp TaskRunner] DEBUG [traceId= spanId=] [reqId=] [sessionId=]o.internal.concurrent.TaskRunner - Q10004 finished run in 314 µs: OkHttp ConnectionPool
```

I did add micrometer tracing to the project which is injected to the OkHttp client as an interceptor.

I wonder if this is keeping the application alive or might there be another cause?

End of pipeline:

```
2023-12-06T13:30:54.8987966Z ##[error]The operation was canceled.
2023-12-06T13:30:54.8999608Z ##[section]Async Command Start: Publish test results
2023-12-06T13:30:54.9000170Z ##[section]Async Command End: Publish test results
2023-12-06T13:30:54.9000916Z ##[section]Finishing: Build
```

and

```
##[error]The job running on agent linux-xxx ran longer than the maximum time of 60 minutes. For more information, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2077134
```

How to make the pipeline properly exit the stage?

Comment: It's recommended to share your pom.xml, pipeline definition, and more error screenshot in the statement. In addition, to narrow down the issue, please checkout the repo to local and run the same `mvn verify...` command, will it exist successfully? Please check exit code by `echo $?` , does it return zero?